# How to fix wp-admin not coming in the url issue in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I am working on wordpress website https://www.iskconujjain.com suddenly some issues are coming although I have not done any major change in the website.

- wp-admin are not coming in any admin url.
- I am trying to change the Permalinks setting but it is not saving.
- All pages are redirecting to home page although in the url having another page path.

Comment: Go to admin panel then Setting->permalink and choose Plain option and save it.

Comment: @ManishNegi I have tried but setting are not saving.

Comment: OK just remove your .htaccess and check

Answer (score 0):

for solve this problem you must regenerate permalink-

For solve it go to Settings > Permalink and save it.

Let me know.

Comment: as I mentioned that permalinks settings are not saving.